# What happens when MySQLdb.executemany() encounters an exception?

Tags: sql, mysql-python

What happens when MySQLdb.executemany() encounters an exception? I was wondering because right now I have a 1062 "duplicate entry" error. This is fine. I can look through my code to find out the problem later. However, I want to know if after encountering the exception, does executemany() stop and raise the exception or continue and execute all remaining inserts?

Thanks.